# set_values call with variable field name

Tags: r, rvest

How can I submit a variable in the `set_values` function in the `rvest` package?

I do not have any problem when I call the function in this way

```
actions <- set_values(form, "stream"="test")
```

where "stream" is the field name in my form

but if a declare a variable and use it to call set_values I get an error

```
temp <- "stream"
actions <- set_values(form, temp="test")
```

> Error: Unknown field names: temp

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `set_values(form, temp="test")`, `temp` is serving as the name of an argument of the `set_values` function, not as a local variable.

If you want to get the argument name from a variable, you could build a list of named arguments, and pass this to the function using `do.call`.

```
temp <- "stream"

arguments <- list(form, "test")
names(arguments) <- c("form", temp)
do.call(set_values, arguments)
```

Same idea, a little more concise:

```
temp <- "stream"
do.call(set_values, setNames(list(form, "test"), c("form", temp)))
```

Or if you prefer, you can match the first argument by position instead of by name:

```
temp <- "stream"
do.call(set_values, c(list(form), setNames("test", temp)))
```

Comment: Note that this answer is not specific to rvest or set_values.  It's just a way of getting an argument name from a variable.

Comment: Whoops, fixed that for you.  You can include form in the list of named arguments as well.

Comment: mmmm
this is what I get
do.call(set_values, setNames(list(form, 'test'), c('form', temp)))
Error in as.vector(y) : argument "form" is missing, with no default

Comment: Can you provide the value you're using for `form`?  It works with this example: `form <- html_form(read_html("http://www.google.com"))[[1]]; temp <- 'q'; do.call(set_values, setNames(list(form, 'test'), c('form', temp)))`

Comment: One way I can reproduce your error is if I make the name of the first argument something other than `"form"`.  E.g., `do.call(set_values, setNames(list(form, "test"), c("form1", temp)))`  Maybe that's what you did?  Actually, you can leave out the name if you want (see my edit).

Comment: I used your last proposal, by position instead of by name, and it work nice! Thank you, you've been very helpful

Comment: Happy to help. Please don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted" since it solved your problem. :)